# Is there an easy way to get the \frontmatter \mainmatter, and \backmatter in a LaTeX report?

Tags: report, front-matter

I'm writing my thesis using the `report` class, which does not support the `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter`, or `\backmatter` commands. However, I really like the idea of having Roman numeral page numbering for the abstract and other front-matter items as provided by `\frontmatter`. Is there an easy way to import this (or similar) functionality into the `report` class?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The easiest way is to use the `book` class. The difference are minimal. The layout is essentially the same if you call `\documentclass[oneside]{book}` and then `\pagestyle{plain}`. For the abstract just use `\chapter{abstract}`; there's no reason for it being treated differently.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As egreg said, the easiest way is to use `book` since the main difference between `book` and `report` is that it has these commands. however if you just want the page number switching without the switch in functionality of chapter to appendix in the back matter
you can simply copy the definitions from book, ignoring the `@mainmatter` switch:

```
\makeatletter

\newcommand\frontmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
  %\@mainmatterfalse
  \pagenumbering{roman}}

\newcommand\mainmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
 % \@mainmattertrue
  \pagenumbering{arabic}}

\newcommand\backmatter{%
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
 % \@mainmatterfalse
   }

\makeatother
```

Comment: I would also add to `\frontmatter` (resp. `\mainmatter`, `\backmatter`) `\renewcommand\thechapter{}` (resp. `\renewcommand\thechapter{\Arabic{chapter}}`, `\renewcommand\thechapter{\Alph{chapter}}`.

Comment: @Randy Randerson: `\Arabic{chapter}` should be `\arabic{chapter}`, I guess.