# Contents and remerciements (acknowledgements) in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I'd like the make the contents and the acknowledgements appear in the table of contents just like the picture below.
Can you tell me how ?

Thanks a lot

[image]

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\slshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\slshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\graphicspath{{Images/}}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{headings}
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introduction}
Some text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, add your MWE.

Comment: `\pagenumbering` resets the page counter, so you have two pages numbered arabic one (acknowledgements, introduction) and one page numbered roman one (Contents). Probably the easiest way to fix it is to use the `book` class with `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`, see e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154646/is-there-an-easy-way-to-get-the-frontmatter-mainmatter-and-backmatter-in-a-l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the table of contents, use the lines

```
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{}Contents}
\tableofcontents
```

If your document class starts chapters on the next page (like article and report classes) instead on the next odd page (like book classes or report classes with the `twoside` option), replace `\cleardoublepage` by `\clearpage`.

For the acknowledgements, use

```
\chapter*{Remerciements (Acknowledgements)}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{}Remerciements (Acknowledgements)}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked fine but those entries are indented in the table of contents. Is there a way to intend them a bit less ?

Comment: In your example document the entries are also indented, aligned with the section entries. This is why they are also indented in my answer. If you want to have them flush left, remove `\numberline{}`.