# How to do proper page numbering in Latex for thesis?

Tags: page-numbering, thesis, roman-numerals

I'm trying to do proper paging for my thesis as per my university format. According to that, Roman numbers should start from the Acknowledgment page till TOC and after that Arabic numbering. Acknowledgment and pages after that should be in TOC. I have done that but somehow it gives the same "**I**" for 3 pages before TOC. I am sharing the initial code and packages of my document.

```
 \documentclass[preprint,authoryear,12pt]{report}
    \usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
    \newenvironment{Acknowledgements}
    {\renewcommand\abstractname{\LARGE{\textit{Acknowledgements}}}\begin{abstract}} {\end{abstract}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\frontmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
  %\@mainmatterfalse
  \pagenumbering{Roman}}
\newcommand\mainmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
 % \@mainmattertrue
  \pagenumbering{arabic}}
\makeatother
    %%%%-----------Thesis starts here--------------------------------%%%%%%%


     \begin{document}
     \frontmatter{
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}
    \begin{Acknowledgements}
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \begin{quote}
    \small{{ I acknowledge who ever answers my question}}
    \end{quote}
    \end{Acknowledgements}
    \clearpage
    %%%%%%This is where i start counter for number%%%%%%
    \newpage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
    \begin{abstract}
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    Its abstract
    \end{abstract}
    %%%%---Abstract Urdu starts here%%%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract in Urdu}
    \includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={},width=\textwidth]{UrduAbstract.pdf}
    %%%%Till this page I get "I" on my pdf%%%%
    \cleardoublepage
    \tableofcontents
    \pagebreak
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
    \listoffigures
    \pagebreak
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
    \listoftables
}
   \mainmatte{}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) and thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: actually I have posted all the packages and initial form of my latex code just to know if any of the packages or format of the thesis causes the problem I have. On my acknowledgment, Abstract, and the one where i have uploaded a pdf pages, latex generates roman "I". I don't understand why? why doesn't it change after the acknowledgment page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `documentclass` `book` it is possible, using `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`.
The pages after `\frontmatter` by default will be numbered with small roman numbers, the rest with arabic.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \pagenumbering{Roman} %Add this if you want I,II,III... instead of i,ii,iii...
    \chapter*{Preliminaries}
    \lipsum[1]
    \clearpage
    \lipsum[2]
    \clearpage
    \lipsum[3]
    \mainmatter
    \chapter*{Main Content}
    \lipsum[1]
    \clearpage
    \lipsum[2]
    \clearpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I have used report class and my thesis is in its complete form except for this issue. I don't know if I change the class at this point how many more changes I have to do :(.

Comment: I would refer to this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154666/81639 Here @DavidCarlisle says that there is no essential difference between `report` and `book`, but you can also define `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` in the preliminaries.

Comment: Okay, ill try that too. But how to add this in preliminaries? I'm sorry not very good at Latex. I also want to know what's wrong in my code?

Comment: @ConscientiousMominate Your code is too long to check. You should the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at this guide: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/81639 (cf. Philip Imhof's comment). From DavidCarlisle's answer you can copy the definitions for `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` and paste before `\begin{document}`

Comment: I have used this technique you mentioned but the problem persists it still gives **I I I** till TOC. Which I think is due to my Acknowledgement and Abstract because I use abstract environment for them and they don't have page numbers un till I use '\thispagestyle{plain}'. Can this be a reason? I'm editing my code so you can check.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. As I guessed the problem was because of using Abstract Environment. I have removed these environments. Now the numbering is fine :)